# Check for directional derivative and show that $f(1,1,1) > f(0,0,0)$ when given the partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm kinda lost in this exercise

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^1$ and   $\forall x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^{3}$ 
>   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(x)=x_{2}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(x)=x_{1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{3}}(x) > -1$$
>   Check if $f$ has a directional derivative in point $(1,2,3)$ and direction $v = (2,1,0)$. If so, what's the value of it? Also show that $f(1,1,1) > f(0,0,0)$.

Alright, when it comes to checking the directional derivative we can (since the function is of class $C^1$ that it is differentiable in all $x$ from the interior of its domain $\Omega$. Therefore it is differentiable in $(1,2,3)$ so it has a directional derivative which equals : $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(x)(v_{1}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(x)(v_{2})+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{3}}(x)(v_{3})$$ but how am I supposed to count it if we don't know what the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is? (EDIT: Ok, $v_{3}$ is $0$ so this one doesnt matter :)) Also, how should I do the 2nd part of this exercise?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I do not understand your notation: which are the components of $a_1$, when you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1)=x$? The result of the partial derivative at a given point in $\mathbb R^{3}$, let us say $a_1$, is a scalar. How are $a_1$ and $x$ related?

Comment: changed it, sorry. got it messed up a bit

Comment: Thanks for the modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directional derivative of $f$ at a point $(x,y,z)$ in the direction of a vector $v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)\cdot v_x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z)\cdot v_y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z)\cdot v_z.
$$
In the specific case asked in the question, this is
$$
2\cdot2+1\cdot1+(?)\cdot0=5.
$$
Using the path $t\mapsto(t,t,t)$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$, one gets
$$
f(1,1,1)-f(0,0,0)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)(t,t,t)\,\mathrm dt\gt\int_0^1(t+t-1)\,\mathrm dt=0.
$$